# Ruby on Rails - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, git, assets

I am using Rails 3.2.13, I have cloned one project from git repo. CSS styles are working fine. But whole javascript plugins are not loading. In console I am getting some Javascript errors like below,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

In application.js,

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Even after precompile also it is not working.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you including jQuery?

Comment: Yes... Moreover it is working project which i have cloned. Only in my local system it is not working. In gem list, I found jquery-rails (3.0.4, 1.0.19)

Comment: Typically, this error message means you are not including jQuery in your project

Comment: Sorry... I didn't get you. Please tell me briefly.

Comment: Probably your jquery link is broken. You might to update it

Comment: In my project, I have "jquery-rails (3.0.4, 1.0.19)" gem.

Comment: you've run `bundle install`? If you use Chrome you can open developer console and see whether Jquery is being loaded properly.

Comment: Yes. I have done with the bundle install & in console application.js file is loading along with error.

Comment: Probably that's not a jquery issue. The first error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` prevents the loading of jquery so the next errors are a consequence of the first one. 
Can you identify the portion of code referenced by the first error?

Answer (score 0):

Update : Got into this problem on one of my machines.

Not sure what is the exact root cause of the problem but this a way around to overcome this issue.

1. Please make sure the below gem is installed.

   gem install sprockets
2. Run the following command

   rake assets:precompile

To know more about the assets pipeline refer http://asciicasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, please try and let me know the result.

Comment: Hi, I have already fixed this issue by adding config.assets.debug = true to environment file. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh it must be `development.rb`

Comment: @ShruthiR this worked for me but it would be great to know why. Details appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had this exact problem with rails 3.2.1 after upgrading to mavericks on my mac.  After researching i updated rails to 3.2.18 which solved the problem.  Apparently some versions of sprockets have proplems with the asset pipeline.  checkout more info at https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/352